# Auto resize textarea after auto add value

Tags: javascript, html, textarea

I have a working dropdown which adds text to textarea.
And i'm trying to make textarea resizable. Its working, but only if i press a key on it.
I'm using this one: http://jsfiddle.net/chim/53eAy/
 and my code:

```
mydropdown.onchange = function(){
//document.getElementById("message").value = "";
 mytextbox.value = mytextbox.value  + this.value; }

$('#fin-message').delegate( 'textarea', 'keyup', function (){
$(this).height( 0 );
$(this).height( this.scrollHeight );
}); 
$('#fin-message').find( 'textarea' ).keyup();
```

I know that a problem is in **keyup** but what shoud i change on?